# Overflow:auto hides content

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

I am working on the following demo which uses snap.js and chart.js on my website

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/9/)

I added some JavaScript to display a content from chart.js while you scroll, but seems like it is in some trouble with the following style:

Line 10 - CSS:   `overflow: auto;`

Which hides the content. If I delete this style it works perfectly:

[DEMO2 JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/10/) (without overflow)

Should I create a `#canvas` style to let me display it in front of the other content? Without deleting the properties of snap.js?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `overflow:auto` is hiding your absolute positioned element. This happens because absolutely positioned elements are essentially taken out of the DOM flow and so  because the parent container has nothing to give it height, your absolute positioned element is hidden.

What you'd be better doing is not using absolute positioning, or giving the container a specific height. That or floating the element left and using a clearfix (my favorite is the :after variation).

Comment: I am not very good at CSS but I tried float: left as you suggested and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - just remember to also use a clearfix because “float” basically “floats” the element above the parent element in the Z-axis so you may find that content below does not appear where you expect it to. The clearfix (applies to the parent element) forces the parent element to consider the floating child as taking up space and sets the height accordingly.

Comment: .parent:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}